# Remove pattern form filenames

Tags: linux, filenames

I have many files named as

```
01- El monstruo del lago ness [www.newpct.com].avi
```

or

```
Inspector gadchet 01- El monstruo del lago ness.avi
```

In the two types, I want to change to this

```
01- El monstruo del lago ness.avi
```

Is there any script in bash to remove a pattern from many files at one? (the pattern could be at the begining, at the end, or in the middle of the file)

P:there are spaces between words

Comment: We need more information. For instance, why "Inspector gadchet" has to be removed? What part of the string has to be kept? BTW: Piracy is a crime! Gotcha! :P

Comment: That string needs to be removed because I want to keep only the chapter title and the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have `rename` (the one that comes with perl), the following might work for you:

```
rename 's/^[^\d]+//;s/\s?\[.*\]//' *.avi
```

Comment: The first part `s/^[^\d]+//` removes anything that isn't a number.  The second part `s/\s?\[.*\]//` removes everything between `[]` and a preceding space (if it exists).

Comment: ok, but this only works with text between [] I want a script where I could set "pattern" to be removed, for example I choose "maked by uchi" or "(2013)" or "----blabla", with no position in particular

Comment: I'm afraid that if you have doubts even after the [explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19160837/remove-patter-form-filenames/19161222?noredirect=1#comment28344415_19161222) you need to read a manual on regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different solutions, including something like that

```
for fname in `find ./ -name "*.avi" `; do mv $fname `echo $fname | sed -e 's/pattern/replace/g'`;done
```

Warning, potentially dangerous. Try using `echo` instead of `mv` to see what will be moved.